# How can i upload pdf file on database using php html

Tags: java, php

how can i upload pdf file on html with the same as like on my database. which is has url and file path. so that if im going to retrieve it on android studio i can know where is the path and also the url. please provide me some code that can do as same on my database. i already done this on android studio. but i dont know how can i done this with html

[this is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amc7G.png)

and code but this is done in android studio. i would like to create this also on html same as doing this#

```js
<?php

//importing dbDetails file7     
require_once 'dbDetails.php';

//this is our upload folder
$upload_path = 'AndroidPdfUpload/';

//Getting the server ip
$server_ip = "files.000webhost.com";

//creating the upload url
$upload_url = 'https://cedportfolio.000webhostapp.com/AndroidPdfUpload/';

//response array
$response = array();


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    //checking the required parameters from the request
    if(isset($_POST['name']) and isset($_FILES['pdf']['name'])){

        //connecting to the database
        $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME) or die('Unable to Connect...');

        //getting name from the request
        $name = $_POST['name'];

        //getting file info from the request
        $fileinfo = pathinfo($_FILES['pdf']['name']);

        //getting the file extension
        $extension = $fileinfo['extension'];

        //file url to store in the database
        $file_url = $upload_url . getFileName() . '.' . $extension;

        //file path to upload in the server
        $file_path = $upload_path . getFileName() . '.'. $extension;

        //trying to save the file in the directory
        try{
            //saving the file
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'],$file_path);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `topics` (`id`, `url`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, '$file_url', '$name');";

            //adding the path and name to database
            if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){

                //filling response array with values
                $response['error'] = false;
                $response['url'] = $file_url;
                $response['name'] = $name;
            }
            //if some error occurred
        }catch(Exception $e){
            $response['error']=true;
            $response['message']=$e->getMessage();
        } 
        //closing the connection
        mysqli_close($con);
    }else{
        $response['error']=true;
        $response['message']='Please choose a file';
    }
    
    //displaying the response
    echo json_encode($response);
}

/*
We are generating the file name
so this method will return a file name for the image to be upload
*/
function getFileName(){
    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME) or die('Unable to Connect...');
    $sql = "SELECT max(id) as id FROM topics";
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));

    mysqli_close($con);
    if($result['id']==null)
        return 1;
    else
        return ++$result['id'];
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO doesn't work like Google translate. People here don't convert codes written in one language to another for the OP.

Comment: It would be nice to know more about the question. like if you are using just php or a framework with it such as laravel or codeigniter. Then I can help you out.

Comment: oopsss sorry. im not good in english. but code on above is code on php also however those are works for android studio

Comment: up still no one answered it

Comment: if you cant understand my question. please refer to image. i want to upload on html as same as u see on database. but i dont know how to code it in html